# Exception to the minimum answer character count

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers

Sometimes a user just needs a single command line answer. To be most efficient (The mantra of the SE community) it would make sense just to give them a single command to run rather than appending frivolous language to the end of what would be a very concise answer.

Maybe questions tagged with the command-line tag can omit this rule?

Answer (score 4):

I tend to disagree - its often useful to talk a little bit more about *why* the command works, than what the command is. Decomposing and explaining the command adds a lot.

Comment: But, taking the question literally often times the user doesn't care about why the command does what it does but rather "I just need some output from the system, how do I do it?" Example: http://superuser.com/questions/697461/how-do-i-find-the-remaining-space-on-an-external-drive

Note the useless text included before the answer, or rather the comment.

Comment: Not a great question - there's little to no research effort there. A better way to do that as an answer would be 'You can use df -h with the h flag doing human readble formatting'

Comment: Its a great answer. and the more upvotes there are for the answer the more relevant it is.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/697507/10165 This is how I'd answer it. It makes it much more useful for other people looking for an answer to the same question (and if someone DID have a reliable way to detect an external hdd, I want to know about it ;p)

Answer (score 4):

Having a good answer which is less than the minimum length is rare<sup>*</sup>, but when it happens you can add random information which is not displayed by using HTML comments.

(`<!-- My extra comment here -->`)

---

<sup>*</sup>: I think I ran into it two or three times since I got a SE account, which averages to once per half year or once per 600 answers.